# node-gyp error while doing npm install gulp-sass

Tags: npm, node-gyp

I am trying to install gulp sass on macOS mojave, but I get node-gyp errors and do not know, how to fix them... does anyone have an idea? Would be very helpful! Thx!

https://www.dropbox.com/s/1bzasbzajybjaul/2021-04-25T15_01_17_367Z-debug.log?dl=0

Philip

Answer (score 0):

You are using Node 16 which node-sass does not support at moment, the ticket is still Open here https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/3077
Check supported environment https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases

[image]

til now downgrade your node version is better solution